# Does Charles Shaw wine contain animal blood & feces?

Tags: nutrition, consumer-products, safety, blood

A post by Chris Knox on Quora was [quoted](http://gothamist.com/2014/08/08/two_buck_chuck_producers_deny_alleg.php) on Gothamist, talking about Charles Shaw wine (aka "Two Buck Chuck"), says:

> "And it not only grabs ripe grapes, but unripe and down right rotten ones as well and throws them all together. Add to that leaves, stems and any rodents, birds, or insects that may have made those vines their home—they all get thrown into the bin as well. And guess what? You think there's going to be any sorting when that truck arrives at the winery (or should I say processing facility)? Nope. Everything, and I do mean everything (including all those unripe grapes, rotten grapes, leaves, stems, birds, rodents, and insects) gets tossed into the crusher and transferred to large tanks to ferment."

Is it true that "Two Buck Chuck" "tosses" "rodents, birds, or insects" "into the crusher and transferred to large tanks to ferment"?

Comment: How much qualifies as a "remnant?" Government regulates how much foreign matter can be in food products. The rules don't state 0. It's common for practically all foods to contain foreign matter, even "gross" things. Although they're typically in harmless quantities, and they're often rendered non-harmful/non-gross by processes such as baking or, in this case, fermentation.

Comment: Who claims or believes that the wine contains feces?

Comment: @Articuno That as well as blood is implied.  Should the title be more literal?

Comment: It should not add what isn't in the claim. It doesn't need to be a literal and exact reproduction though. It can be a summary. Specifically, the claim is only that the debris and animals make it to the fermentation vats, not that anything other than wine ends up in the actual bottles.

Comment: It seems like the same concern could apply to any mechanically harvested crop. I'm not clear why a particular brand of a particular product should be singled out.

Comment: I would also note that certian wines are made using different maturity and conditions of grapes.  There is a parasitic fungus that causes grapes to rot that is used to make a specific type of wine that is enjoyed by many who enjoy fine wines.